# How to use preg_match to validate Kenyan phone numbers?

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, phone-number

I would like to add a phone number in a registration form.

Users will need to input username, email, phone number and password. All these fields will be REQUIRED including the phone number.

I'm based in Kenya so I would like to limit the phone number to 13 characters including the + (sign).

The number should like: `+25470164XXXX` OR `070164XXXX` both formats are acceptable.

Kindly assist me on how to implement this using preg_match function in PHP.

This is what I am currently using:

```
if (preg_match('/^(\+254|0)[1-9]\d{13}$/', $phone_number) ) {
    echo json_encode( array( 'success' => false, 'msg' => esc_html__('Invalid Phone Number (do not use letters, special characters or spaces)!', 'houzez-login-register') ) );
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Can you describe in words what is the format? It's hard to understand just from your examples.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution is:

```
preg_match('/^(\+254|0)\d{9}$/', $phone_number);
```

or maybe better

```
preg_match('/^(\+254|0)[1-9]\d{8}$/', $phone_number);
```

please apply more rules on your own.

Comment: Tried to help. You are right that the RE is suboptimal, there should be rules for the nine digits, [1-9]\d{8} or more complicated.